# Ubuntu 18.04 & KeePass2 Chinese char problem

Tags: 18.04, chinese, keepass

I have KeePass2 installed in Ubuntu 18.04 (in a dual boot with Windows 8.1), I'm sharing KeePass db between Win & Ubuntu, KeePass in Win I can see Chinese char without problem, but in Ubuntu, Chinese char are replaced with squares. I asked question in KeePass forum and they said it has something to do with Ubuntu and not KeePass. How can I fix it?
ps: it's a new install, so I haven't tested a lot of apps yet, but so far I only noticed showing garbage in KeePass.

Comment: Further checking I noticed that in KeePass, there's an entry in Tools > Options > Interface > Advanced > Force using system fonts (Linux) is checked, so I guess for some reason KeePass is picking a wrong font from Ubuntu. Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I went to Tools > Options > Interface, at the bottom there's a button Select List Font, and I clicked on it, it opened another window with lists of fonts/script to select, the trouble is if I select script Big5 (which is to display Chinese char), I can see the Chinese char without trouble, the problem is it changed also the western script to the same font. Not sure if I can select different fonts for different script.